# what is the difference between np.random.seed vs random_state?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

What is the difference between `np.random.seed` and `random_state` in python when applying machine learning algorithms?

Comment: They come from different libraries - the first one from Numpy, while the second one from scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the seed for any function that calls to `np.random...` we will use `np.random.seed` . The effect of setting the seed is global as it will end up effecting all functions.

```
>>> np.random.seed(1234)
>>> np.random.uniform(0, 1, 5)
array([0.19151945, 0.62210877, 0.43772774, 0.78535858, 0.77997581])
>>> np.random.rand(3)
array([0.27259261, 0.27646426, 0.80187218])
>>> np.random.seed(1234)
>>> np.random.rand(3)
array([0.27259261, 0.27646426, 0.80187218])
```

If you dont want to change the global seed value and only want to set the state for one task, random_state is used.

```
>>> r = np.random.RandomState(1234)
>>> r.uniform(0, 1, 5)
array([0.19151945, 0.62210877, 0.43772774, 0.78535858, 0.77997581])
>>> np.random.rand(3)
array([0.17292499, 0.24859476, 0.90838076])
>>> np.random.rand(3)
array([0.26393139, 0.69557975, 0.32776094])
```

Comment: OP obviously asks about the `random_state` argument frequently used in scikit-learn, and not the Numpy `RandomState`

Comment: I dont see the obvious here. The question does not have a scikit-learn tag with it hence I answered it with numpy.

Comment: The obvious comes from the explicit mention of machine learning in the question body, the `machine-learning` tag, a new user who evidently is not familiar with the available tags (notice the absence of a `numpy` one, too), plus the mention of `random_state` (neither "random state" nor `RandomState`), i.e. the exact argument used in scikit-learn

Comment: Of course we can just wait for the OP to confirm/clarify